# how do I find all exe files using command line for windows?

Tags: windows

I'm a newbie. I am trying to figure out how to use the command line. Please could you tell me what command I should enter so that I can get a list of all the exe files on my computer. thanks.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the dir functionality to search the directory and all of its children directories while filtering on a particular file type.

```
dir  /s /b *.exe | findstr /v .exe.
```

Sources: [dir](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/dir), [findstr](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/findstr)

If you are wondering why we need `findstr`: the `dir` command finds all the files that contain `.exe`, not necessarily at the end. So it will find `program1.exe`, which is good, but also `program2.executable` and `program3.exe.zip`, which we don't want. To exclude the wrong results we pipe the output of `dir` into `findstr /v`, which takes only the lines that do not match the regular expression `.exe.`, which means: any character, followed by `exe`, followed by any character.

All in all, in plain English the whole command means: list all the files which contain `.exe`, but discard those that have some characters after `.exe`. In other words, list only the files that end with `.exe`.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to find all the executable files that are on the path and/or in the current directory, i.e., all the files you can run from the command line without specifying a path, this should work:

```
where *.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

To get names of all .exe files , that are currently running then type `tasklist` in cmd.

http://ss64.com/nt/tasklist.html

Answer (score 0):

Here's another method I use a lot for tasks like this.

Open powershell and navigate to your root directory by entering the command

```
cd c:/
```

cd stands for change directory, and is an alias for the command "Set-Location". We are setting the location to C:/

Next run the following command:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter "*.exe" -Recurse
```

Get-ChildItem is a function that gets the files and folders in a file system drive, and runs on whatever directory you're current at by default.

-Filter "*.exe" is an argument that specifies to only find filenames which end in ".exe". (The * is a type of regular expression notation).

-Recurse is an argument that specifies to search all child directories. This will make your function run on "C:/", but also all child directories of C:/, and all child directories of those directories and so on. This will allow you to search the entire drive.